# Benefits of using ViewModel vs DataContracts in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What are the benefits of using ViewModel vs DataContracts when you are building a product? I am looking for pros and cons for both.

Few benefits I can think of using Viewmodel is it can have presentation Logic,

1. If I need to display the full user name, my viewmodel can have full
   name which is concatenation of First Name and Last Name from
   Contracts.
2. I can mention Data Annotations Like Required and
   DisplayName which are view specific.
3. In Visual Studio I can simply click Add View in controller action and generate view using scaffolding.

Any other benefits? The Guideline in my team is to use DataContracts instead. So I need more details to convince.

Comment: DataContracts are for WCF (SOAP). Is that what you mean here?

Answer (score 2):

They aren't really used for the same thing.  ViewModels are used to structure how members in the class are presented on the View. DataContracts are used to pass data between things like Services and websites.  View Models are a way of separating the entity model from a display model, that way you can model data from a database and not have it coupled to your view layer.

Comment: I agree. The right answer is probably to use both, even if DataContracts just means EF Entities.

Answer (score 0):

when your data contract separate from your viewmodel your product has more flexibility to change presentation layer to another .for example you use datacontract as viewmodel in a wpf application .if you want use mvvm you have to change your datacontract struct and implement INotifypropertyChange for call RaisePropertyChanged method in properties set.now you want have a web application too .do you need to call RaisePropertyChanged in web application?!!(it's just a sample).when you use viewmodels you don't worry about datacontracts when change your presentation layer .